# Weird artifact showing through nine-patch button

Tags: android, user-interface, button, nine-patch

I have created a simple 9patch to use for my button graphic.

[image: 9patch example]

When I view it as part of the layout editor, it appears to look okay.

[image]

However, when I run it in an emulator I get this ugly looking artifact/relic around the bottom left/top right corners.

[image]

Does anyone know what causes this, and how I might fix it? I'm currently applying the 9patch using the android:background property.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think,  you should test it on real device. I had similar problem with AVD. When I connected my LG everything was OK.

Comment: Same issue appaears on the real device.